# Why can't a Carnot engine heat sink be at absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

We know that for a Carnot engine the efficiency is given by $1-(T_2/T_1)$, but why can't a real engine have $T_2=0\,{\rm K}$?

I know that the efficiency cannot be $1$, but why can't we make the heat sink temperature zero Kelvin?

Comment: Even if you could develop a setup for achieving essentially absolute zero for a reservoir, you would have to expend energy elsewhere to maintain its temperature at absolute zero as it absorbs heat in your primary process.  So, the net result would be lower overall efficiency.  In ordinary power generation cycles, Mother Nature  (or a cooling tower) maintains the temperature of our cold reservoir, which doesn't cost us much extra energy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller, that's an answer.